# while in foreach loop just echo's once

Tags: php, xml, foreach, while-loop

I try to compare the temperatures of an XML file with my database.
But it's only comparing the first of 7 datas.
That means the while loop only works on the first pass, but why?

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"); //get temperatures from databse
    foreach ($xml->forecast as $forecast) { //just one pass (one forecast in the xml)
        foreach ($forecast->time as $time) { // 7 passes (7 dates in the xml)
            echo $time['day'] . "<br />";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { //This loop just works on the first pass
                if ($row['mintemp'] <= $time->temperature['day'] && $time->temperature['day'] <= $row['maxtemp']) {                        
                    echo $row['namekl'] . " | Rating (" . $row['rating'] . ")" . "<br />";
                }
            }
            echo "<br />";
        }
    }
```

I usually expect the following result:

```
2013-07-19
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-20
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-21
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-22
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-23
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-24
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-25
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)
```

but my results look like this:

```
2013-07-19
Databse 1 | Rating (5)
Databse 2 | Rating (5)
Databse 3 | Rating (3)

2013-07-20

2013-07-21

2013-07-22

2013-07-23

2013-07-24

2013-07-25
```

Comment: well you know its for loop... it will keep executing and the last one gets echoed when the loop exits....

Comment: I dont get it...the loop works but the while just works once...where is the problem?

Comment: try print_r(mysql_fetch_array($query));

Comment: sorry i miss read the code previously, put $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"); in your foeach loop, then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the `foreach` loops, it's in how you're using MySQL. `mysql_fetch_array` returns you all the results from the whole table the first time you call it, then has nothing to return on every other pass through the loop...

Comment: thank you! I put my query in the foreach loops and now it is working!

Comment: @TimRucker if the table doesn't change during the loop, you could speed things up buy fetching the table once, into an array, and looping over the array multiple times. Probably doesn't matter much if the table is small and the query simple, but hitting the database multiple times unnecessarily can be slow...

Comment: I've also been thinking about it. Thank you :D

Comment: No problem. If you're on a recent PHP, mysqli and fetch_all are probably helpful.